# Bar chart or histogram

Tags: statistics

What's the difference between a bar chart and a histogram?

Comment: Please see http://stattrek.com/AP-Statistics-1/Histogram.aspx

Comment: @Americo Tavares: Thats what i have posted as an answer, adding an extra link.

Comment: Maybe more suitable at http://stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @Chandru1: I realized that but I started writting my comment when there was no answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With bar charts, each column represents a group defined by a categorical variable; and with histograms, each column represents a group defined by a quantitative variable.

See this link: http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_difference_between_Bar_chart_and_a_frequency_histogram

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with wiki answers, which although it's partially correct, completely misses the main point.  The *heights* in a bar chart represent counts.  You can use a bar chart for this purpose with categorical data or with binned "continuous" variates; either is fine.  The *areas* in a histogram represent *relative frequencies* or *proportions per unit value* of a continuous variate.  A histogram thus is a discrete approximation to a frequency or probability density function, whereas a bar chart has no such meaning (except accidentally when it's really serving as a histogram!).  The distinction comes to the fore when the bars in a histogram have varying widths.

Reference: Freedman, Pisani, Purves, *Statistics*.  (Any of the first through fifth editions should be fine.)